# comparing HTML text content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where a specific `div` shows the ID for the user's "system role" like so:

```
<div id="systemRoleIndicator" style="display: none;">
    <p>Z</p>
</div>
```

I can detect the value fine with jQuery, but I can't seem to actually use it for anything. For instance, I never receive the completion message in this code:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var role = $("#systemRoleIndicator").text();
    alert("Your role is: " + role); //displays proper value
    if (role == "Z") {
        alert("Code completed!");
    }
</script>
```

Why might this be? Am I missing something about comparing strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text for `#systemRoleIndicator` will also return leading and trailing space near p node. which returns text `" Z "` and not `"Z"`.You need to either compare with the text of p element.:

```
var role = $("#systemRoleIndicator p").text();
```

or trim the text content of `#systemRoleIndicator`:

```
var role = $("#systemRoleIndicator").text().trim();
```

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!